# SQL Sort by Alphanumerical Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, alphanumeric

So I have looked a few different example on here, however none of them seem to be working for me.

Here is a sample of what I need sorted:

```
Alpha #1
Beta #3
Charlie #2
Alpha #2
Charlie #1
Beta #2
Beta #1
Alpha #10
```

And when sorted I would like

```
Alpha #1
Alpha #2
Alpha #10
Beta #1
Beta #2
Beta #3
Charlie #1
Charlie #2
```

However when I use the following query, `Alpha #10` does not follow the desired rule.

```
ORDER BY 
Case When IsNumeric(LEFT(MachineName,1)) = 1 
     Then CASE When IsNumeric(MachineName) = 1 
               Then Right(Replicate('0',20) + MachineName + '0', 20)
               Else Right(Replicate('0',20) + MachineName, 20) 
          END
     When IsNumeric(LEFT(MachineName,1)) = 0 
     Then Left(MachineName + Replicate('',21), 20)
End
```

I get this instead:

```
Alpha #1
Alpha #10
Alpha #2
...
```

I am new to `LEFT` and `RIGHT`, so I might be doing something wrong, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(v VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Alpha #1'),
('Beta #3'),
('Charlie #2'),
('Alpha #2'),
('Charlie #1'),
('Beta #2'),
('Beta #1'),
('Alpha #10'),
('Alpha #')

SELECT * FROM @t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', v) > 1 THEN SUBSTRING(v, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', v) - 1) END, 
         CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', v) > 1 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(v, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', v), LEN(v)) AS INT) END
```

Output:

```
Alpha #
Alpha #1
Alpha #2
Alpha #10
Beta #1
Beta #2
Beta #3
Charlie #1
Charlie #2
```

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the answer, however what if I had a row without a number? For example, `Delta` 

I am getting the error: `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` which I believe is caused because some entries do not have a number in them

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect